# Using Kafka TimestampConverter with microseconds?

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I'm new to Kafka/Avro. My downstream database (Postgres) has a `timestamptz` column. My upstream database (Materialize) produces the following Avro schema for the column:

```
  "type": [
    "null",
    {
      "logicalType": "timestamp-micros",
      "type": "long"
    }
  ]
```

This seems consistent with `timestamptz`, which also stores microseconds. However, I'm getting the following:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "time" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type bigint 
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 207

        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:122)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:581)
        ... 10 more
```

It seems like the Kafka messages contain `bigint`/`long` and `JdbcSinkConnector` doesn't know how to convert it to a timestamp. I tried using Kafka's `TimestampConverter`, but it assumes the input timestamp is in milliseconds.

It doesn't look like `TimestampConverter` supports microseconds directly (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10561)

Is there a way to convert microseconds to milliseconds in Kafka connectors? This can just be a hack, so I don't need to change the Avro schema. If there's a transform to divide by 1000 or remove the last 3 digits, that should work. Is there a way to do this without a custom transform or ksqlDB?

Comment: Any answer to this? I am running into a similar error :/

Comment: The new TimestampConverter supports microseconds, you just need to build it yourself

Comment: Would be Nice to share how you manage to do it :)